# Safe Razor Template Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm an asp.net mvc 3 newbie, I'm developing a site that allow user customize their layout and use razor template engine. Thay could direct edit the template file.

How to retrict user from only allow uses some explicit helper in a template. I dont want user access other dangerous server functions, and only use what I added.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are two cases:

1. You trust your users: in this case you shouldn't be worried as they won't break your site
2. You don't trust your users (most probable): in this case giving them the possibility to directly modify the templates seems a risky affair. You will need a pretty solid sanitizing tool that will filter all other helpers that you don't want. It's just too broad. Giving them the possibility to write markup would be OK with for example some WYSIWYG editor like [WMD](http://wmd-editor.com/) but giving them access to server code is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wonder how razor template can be used as http://www.liquidmarkup.org template engine, user could use all functions that we allow, but not harm server side.

Comment: I am working on a scheme where users provide a layout template, and put some special tags like <object type=BODY> where I will replace with RenderSection after they upload.  It would be basically regular HTML that the user provides(just as you suggest).  The main problem I see is making sure that no Razor/C# code is included in their original upload. I can't render the layout as Html.Raw/Encoded because it is after all, a layout and needs RenderSection calls. I thought about a HTML validator which would catch most things, but some things like href="@(some razor/C#)" would look like valid html.